# how to provide the number of CPUs of a node for a pod

Tags: kubernetes

I would like to put number of CPUs into an env, something like this:

```
  spec:
    containers:
    - name: test-container
      env:
      - name: NUMBER_OF_CPU
        valueFrom:
          fieldRef:
            fieldPath: spec.node.CPU
```

with `kubectl describe nodes` there is an info about the number of CPU of a node:

```
Addresses:
  InternalIP:  127.0.0.1
  Hostname:    host1
Capacity:
 cpu:                8
 ephemeral-storage:  242791844Ki
 hugepages-1Gi:      0
 hugepages-2Mi:      0
 memory:             16271048Ki
 pods:               110
```

So how could I pass this information to a pod? Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

in the `fieldRef` [only annotations, labels, name and namespace are supported.](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.17/#downwardapivolumefile-v1-core) and only from POD object info, this is called [Downward API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/downward-api-volume-expose-pod-information/) .

**From my tests, this command should work for you:**

```
grep -c ^processor /proc/cpuinfo
```

It will count the number of lines starting with "processor" in  `/proc/cpuinfo` which equals to the amount shown in `kubeclt describe node`.

Depending on your use case, you can pass it as ENV or let your app run the command:

```
❯ k describe node gke-cluster-1
Capacity:
  cpu:                        4
  ephemeral-storage:          98868448Ki
  memory:                     15397584Ki
```

Yaml:

```
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: ubuntu
        name: shell-demo-cpu
      env:
      - name: NUMBER_OF_CPU
        value: "grep -c ^processor /proc/cpuinfo"
```

Then call the variable and run it:

```
kubectl exec -it shell-demo-cpu -- /bin/bash

root@gke-cluster-1:/# env
NUMBER_OF_CPU=grep -c ^processor /proc/cpuinfo

root@gke-cluster-1:/# $NUMBER_OF_CPU
4
```

Let me know if it that helps.

Comment: sorry this is not what I need - because I would like to use the value of env variable an not to execute it

Comment: @HiB I see, now that you made it clearer, I'll make some more tests.

Comment: probably I have to create the env variable within the command section before executing the orig command

Comment: @HiB Yes, something like this:
`command: ["/bin/sh","-c"]`
`args: ["export NUMBER_OF_CPU=$(grep -c ^processor /proc/cpuinfo)"]`
but I'm still facing some problems to boot up the pod correctly.

Comment: @HiB Would it be ok if the value is passed on a file by a `InitContainer` in a json file instead of a env var?

Answer (score -1):

You need to pass `args`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: cpu-demo
  namespace: cpu-example
spec:
  containers:
  - name: cpu-demo-ctr
    image: vish/stress
    resources:
      limits:
        cpu: "1"
      requests:
        cpu: "0.5"
    args:
    - -cpus
    - "2"
```

The args section of the configuration file provides arguments for the container when it starts. The -cpus "2" argument tells the Container to attempt to use 2 CPUs.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/assign-cpu-resource/#specify-a-cpu-request-and-a-cpu-limit

Comment: I don't want to define - I want to get it from the system